# Can I add a library from the folder above?

Tags: cmake

I can't add my static library to my project.

I have the following project structure:

```
+ root/
  + CmakeLists.txt // Include all projects
  + Base/
  | + foo.cpp
  | + CmakeLists.txt
  + App1/
  | + app1.cpp
  | + CmakeLists.txt // Requires Base lib
  + App2/
  | + app2.cpp
  | + CmakeLists.txt // Requires Base lib
```

I try to do it in the following way:

`Base` CmakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)

add_library(Base STATIC foo.cpp)
```

`App1` CmakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10.2)

project(App1)
add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} app1.cpp)

include(../Base/CMakeLists.txt)
```

But I have the following error:

```
CMake Error at C:/DPA/Base/CMakeLists.txt:3 (add_library):
  Cannot find source file:

    foo.cpp
```

How I can properly setup library to include in all projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you use such a directory structure. Instead, in `App1/CmakeLists.txt`, go with

```
add_executable(App1 app1.cpp)
target_link_libraries(App1 Base)
```

This declares that `App1` depends on `Base` and shall be linked against that library. "Linking" means not only passing the correct arguments to your linker, it also propagates include flags and other options to the compiler when building `App1` sources.

If you intend to build only parts of your project, you can use an additional argument to `add_executable`, i.e.

```
add_executable(App1 EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL app1.cpp)
```

This way, when you build the default target, `App1` won't be part of the build. You can still build it manually/upon request, e.g. when working with makefiles,

```
make App1
```

will build the executable `App1` and everything that's required for it.

Comment: The last paragraph is misleading: `Base` doesn't need to be defined yet for `target_link_libraries(App1 Base)` to work correctly, so the order of subdirectory addition does not matter.

Comment: @Angew Thanks, I didn't know that!

Comment: Thanks for explanation!
But If I also want to build only `App1`, how I can include `Base` in `App1`?

Comment: If `App1` depends on `Base`, how do you want to "only build `App1`"?

Comment: @lubgr, Sorry, I mean to build only `Base` and `App1`, without `App2`, using `App1/CmakeLists.txt`. Is it possible?

Comment: Ok I understand. I'll edit the answer to include this scenario.

Comment: @Tsyvarev That's not true at all. The distinction whether it's a target or not is done at generate time, not at the time of processing `target_link_libraries` at configure time. Our build system at work relies heavily on this, and I've also just verified it in a small example.

Comment: @Angew: You are right, sorry for noise. I had always assumed that `target_link_libraries` is processed immediately, but simple test shows the opposite. However, I remember some SO questions where the order was important. Maybe, something has been changed in CMake since, e.g., 2.8.12.

Comment: @Tsyvarev It might be that the old property `LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES` was partly evaluated immediately; not sure about that. However, the new `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` and the rest of the `INTERFACE_*` family definitely operates at generate time.